# How to build any framework so that framework user does not need to learn any underlying frameworks used in building the framework?

Tags: spring, frameworks

I am involved in building framework offering financial, non financial mobile services.

Underlying technology we are using is Spring 3.2 framework , especially Spring MVC.

Now Spring MVC offers many features by way of annotations.for example, to create controller just annotate class with ***@Controller*** annotation and you are done.besides this, there are many more things like handlers,adapters, exception resolver.

My question is.
As I already leveraged Spring framework and I know how to use Spring framework or customize by available hook points.and I might had did it but what about my framework users.

Should I create wrappers on above offerings by Spring so that my framework user does not need to know or learn Spring framework?

For example, Spring provides flexibility to register exception handlers to handle exceptions but for that we need to create bean entry for required exception handler and need to register in exception resolvers class and its his job to dig into Spring details to get idea how they have provided exception handlers and all those stuff.

He needs to do exactly same as I already did.

instead of that Should I provide some provision so that user just can define bean entry for their exception handler and register it in my framework provided registry, not in Spring provided bean class?|

Comment: What's the point? Let them use Spring: it's standard, will make them happy to use a non-proprietary framework they can use elsewhere. It's also better tested and documented that anything you could provide yourself.

Comment: ya but as a framework user, I expertized in Spring framework, I will not nullify Spring but whatever User wants , I will provides to him by making use of Spring so that user need not to be do that

Answer (score 0):

Spring already provide all those features, is widely used, is well documented, have thriving community, etc.

You should expose them directly so the user of your framework can easily adapt to your framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to hide Spring.

No matter how hard you try, your abstraction will leak,
and then the API users will need to know Spring anyway.

See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html